# Using CSS to place a line between two divs of changing widths

Tags: javascript, css, divider

I'm CSSing a layout, and the design has used lots of |'s in between two elements that can change size.  I.E.

John      |      Logout

Where John is on the left of the div in question, and Logout is on the right.  With the name being dynamic and changeable, is there any way I can guarantee the line will position in the middle of each?  Should I perhaps quit the CSS approach and just use a little JavaScript function?

```
<div class="top">
    <p class="name">Welcome Jeremy Louelen-Boxen</p>
    <p>|</p> 
    <p class="logout"><a href="#">Logout</a></p>
</div>
```

Edit:
For some more detail, so the line will appear in the middle of the two elements, one (or both are changing size)

```
p       |        logout
john      |      logout
david      |     logout
jonathonan   |   logout
reallylongname | logout
```

Border right doesn't work as it is a static distance from the element, i.e. the padding on the element before the border needs to change depending on the number of characters included.

Thanks for your help all, Dave

Answer (score 0):

```
.top p{
     margin:0 10px 0 10px;
     padding:0 10px 0 10px;
     border-left:1px solid #000;
}

.top p:first-child{
     border-left: none transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don`t use just:

```
.top .name { border-right: 1px solid black }
```

Comment: because it doesn't move correctly depending on the width of elements - thanks for the reply though.

Answer (score 0):

In pure css:

```
.top p:after {
    content: ' | ';
}
.top p:last-child:after {
    content: '';
}
```

Of course, this may not work in old browsers.

Answer (score 0):

A hack, but it works:

```
.top {
    overflow: auto;
}

.top > :first-child {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    border-right: 1px solid gray;
}

.top > :last-child {
    float: right;
    width: 49%;
    text-align: right;
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/DrJyd/2/

( you don't need that `<p>|</p>` element anymore )

Comment: thats cool, but its just as my divs change width (currently the first word is getting much longer than the second word) this will always just be in the middle.  I added an extra bit of explanation to illustrate the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
.top p{float:right}
.top p.name{float:left}
```

that will do it

Comment: hi, thanks for the response, the thing is that I need to have a divider (a | or a border) exactly in the middle of the two elements of variable widths.  the float left and right will get them on the left and right, its the getting the vertical bar in the middle of them that I'm struggling with. thanks

Comment: it looks like logout is always the same length